# Rails PDF Prawn Data Generation from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a file named `report.pdf.prawn`,

which is the view part of my PDF file where we can edit the contents of the PDF file like >>>

```
*pdf=Prawn::Document.new(:page_layout =>:landscape,:page_size => 'A4')
pdf.text"Hello"
head=@headers
headers=[""],[""]
pdf.table headers,
:width => 768,
:size => 11,
:border_style => :underline_header,
:headers => [head.titleize],
:header_color => 'b7e3fe',
:padding=>5*

<<< etc ect...
```

The above just prints like

```
Hello
Header1header2header3
```

I have two values from my controller `>>>  def report <<<` as

`@header` and `@data`

- `@header` gives values like `Header1Header2Header3`
- `@data` gives values like `data11data12data13data21data22data23`

How do i print the values like the format given below on all PDF pages being generated?

```
Header1     Header2    Header3

data11      data12     data13

data21      data22     data23

data31      data32     data33

data41      data42     data33
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cs = [ ]
    @sql_query.each do |column|
         data=[]


         if @headers.include?('data1x')
         column.number
         data << column.number
         end

             if @headers.include?('data2x')
         column.number
         data << column.number
         end

cs << data

end

pdf.table cs,

:width => 768,

:size => 11,

:border_style => :underline_header,

:headers => @header,

:header_color => 'b7e3fe',

:column_widths=>{0=>55,1=>100,2=>70,3=>77,4=>88,5=>90,6=>75,7=>75,8=>75,9=>65,10=>55,11=>55},
:padding=>5
```